# Why isn't my index used

Tags: postgresql

I'm running postgresql-9.1.6 on RHEL 5.8 OS. I got a statement implementing seq scan on which column is indexed.

```
                          Table "public.table"
Column    |         Type          |                Modifiers                
----------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 col1     | character(3)          | not null
 col2     | character varying(20) | not null
 col3     | character varying(20) | 
 col4     | character(1)          | default 0
Indexes:
    "table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (col1, col2)


postgres=# explain analyze select * from table where col1=right('10000081',3);
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..31053.24 rows=5650 width=286) (actual time=3.221..429.950 rows=110008 loops=1)
   Filter: ((col1)::text = '081'::text)
 Total runtime: 435.904 ms
(3 rows)

postgres=# explain analyze select * from table where col1=right('10000081',3)::char(3);
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on table  (cost=3097.81..18602.98 rows=112173 width=286) (actual time=18.125..32.707 rows=110008 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (col1 = '081'::character(3))
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_pkey  (cost=0.00..3069.77 rows=112173 width=0) (actual time=17.846..17.846 rows=110008 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (col1 = '081'::character(3))
 Total runtime: 38.640 ms
(5 rows)
```

and I found that [alter column] is one of the solution....

```
postgres=# alter table table alter column col1 type varchar(3);               
ALTER TABLE
postgres=# explain analyze select * from table where col1=right('10000081',3);
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on table  (cost=160.26..10902.32 rows=5650 width=295) (actual time=20.249..41.658 rows=110008 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((col1)::text = '081'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_pkey  (cost=0.00..158.85 rows=5650 width=0) (actual time=20.007..20.007 rows=110008 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((col1)::text = '081'::text)
 Total runtime: 47.408 ms
(5 rows)
```

What I wonder is WHY???

Comment: Please show us the definition of the index you expect the query to use.

Comment: sorry, table description was missed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid the `char` datatype. It's awful for many reasons, and this is only one of them.

If you stick to `text` or `varchar` you'll have fewer issues with implicit casts and confusing behavior.

Comment: Is there any reference that I can get more information on char type issue?

Comment: @KIM The manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 4):

It looks from the first plan that there is an implicit type cast performed on col1 to match the return type of [right()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html).

```
Filter: ((col1)::text = '081'::text)
```

Evidently the expression right('10000081',3) returns text.

So I would say that yes, you do have to type cast the expression, although an alternative would be to index on (col1)::text -- not my favourite solution though.